# jQuery plugin run even though selector didn't match anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I wrote a jQuery plugin, everything seems fine, until I ran my plugin on an non-existent DOM element. I was expecting that the alert box wouldn't pop up since `$("#div1")` would've returned empty set

### html

```
<div id="div2">hello</div>
```

### javascript

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({myPlugin1: function(options){
        alert('plugin run');
        return this;
    }    
    });
})(jQuery);

$("#div1").myPlugin1();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qcv4/)

Notice the DOM element has id **div2** while the plugin is called on **div1**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plugin extends the jQuery object. An empty selector still returns a jQuery object, so it'll still run.

If you want to check to see if the selector matched anything, you have to do so explicitly:

```
if (this.length == 0) return this;

alert('plugin run');
return this;
```